# GWT css style overriding

Tags: css, gwt, gwt2

I want to override my label color so redfined it one of the css in application using .gwt-label class. However at one specific location in the application, I need a different color. So I did the overriding the css style class in the UI binder of that class using @external

```
   <ui:style field='otherStyle'>
       @external .gwt-Label;
      .gwt-Label { color: #fff; }  

   </ui:style>
```

It works fine but the moment I access this page in the browser, all the labels style take the effect of above style.

Any clue would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use inline css for that or write css on that page with `!important` tag

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use a different style name, and add it to all of the elements you want to be a different color.  You can't selectively choose which version of a single css class to use on different elements.

Comment: I have a lot of label elements which are created from java code and I was striving more for finding a way to control the labels from one place.

Comment: You have to identify which labels should be colored white _somehow_.  Adding a classname to the special elements is a standard solution.  You can still control the definitions of the normal class and the special class from a single place.